# How to make a dictionary from lists?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, nlp

suppose I have a list of words (1000 most frequent words of a file (for summerizing I just wrote 4 of them) like below:

```
list = [p[0] for p in freq.most_common(4)]
```

And another list containing matrices:

```
[[wordVector[0,:]] , [wordVector[1,:]], [wordVector[2,:]],   [wordVector[3,:]]]
```

How can I make a dictionary of them?

```
keys = [p[0] for p in freq.most_common(4)]            
array = numpy.array([[wordVector[0,:]] , [wordVector[1,:]], [wordVector[2,:]], [wordVector[3,:]]])
dic = dict(zip(keys, zip(*array)))
print (dic)
```

this code returns just one of the most frequent word and comma separated values:
[image]

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your data right, I think you just need:

```
dic = dict(zip(keys, array))
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. how can I delete "array" in the output?

Comment: 'array' is just your debugger showing that it is a numpy array.